# Rstudio Addins for documents creation from `Rmd` files

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

How to add addins to Rstudio which allows for conversion of `Rmd`s into ducoments with pandoc ? `rmarkdown` or `knitr` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you need an addin: there is a `Knit` button on the toolbar that does exactly what you described. You can check out the "Get Started" lesson at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the editData package (which seems an rstudio addin, in fact; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/editData/README.html ) in a Rmd (markdown) document.

My Rmd file works fine while I do "Run" actions on the Rmd, but when I attempt to trigger the knitting to html, it breaks knitting at the step to run the editData()

Breaking line says:

mr.fuzzy.distinct <- editData(mr.fuzzy.distinct.orig)

Maybe this could be an example of what the first poster in this thread was talking about?